# How to call a HomeController method from jQuery UI dialog button in MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am new in MVC and I am using MVC 3. I created a function in my `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult AddRole()
{
    return Index();
}
```

this method simply add some data in my list and in my Index.cshtml file I want this method on click of dialog box button which is

```
$("#roleAdd").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add Roles": function () {
             $(this).dialog("close");
             **window.location =  @Url.Action("AddRole", "Home")**
        },
        "Close": function () {
             $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

but my window.location or any other solution not working.   Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $.ajax to make a call:

```
  $.ajax({
           url: '@(Url.Action("AddRole", "Home"))',
           type: 'POST',
           data: { className: cName },// Your parameter
           async: false,
           success: function (result) {
               // What you want to do after the call
           }
       });
```

Hope this help :)